# How to use WinForms host in XAML file OR put it in Toolbox in WPF project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

I've read tutorial how to embed `Form` in `WPF's` `Window` http://tech.pro/tutorial/786/wpf-tutorial-using-winforms-in-wpf I test it and it seems to be easy. But the problem is that I have create `WinForm host` programmatically in the `.cs` file. This is inconvienient to me.

I would like to put it in the XAML to have better control over its size. If it is possible I also would like to add `WinForms` host to toolbox

Comment: What do you want that for? specifically

Comment: @HighCore Thank you for your answer. If you wanna know for what it is needed I can email you about it. I do not want to go offtopic and I know precisely what I need. I need/want/would like to be able to add `WinForms Host` from the xaml level. If you can do it somehow could you post little tutorial as an answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to do that.. but anyhow because the Winform is a top-level control.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Form1 frm = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        frm = new Form1();
        frm.TopLevel = false;
    }

    private void frmMain_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myHost.Child = frm;
    }
}
```

Happy Coding..

This is the accompany XAML...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid x:Name="frmMain" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}" Loaded="frmMain_Loaded">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="myHost" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
    </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Try it out... I assure you it works and..

Comment: @HighCore Is that better? No reason to down-rate the answer before trying.. :) It actually works.

Comment: jeez, am I drunk? I don't see **XAML** anywhere in your answer. I can only see procedural `C#` code.

Comment: Could you please explain why you use class `Form1` in your cs(c#) file?